# viewWillApear not called for UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a class which has `UIImagePickerController` and extends `UIViewController`. But **viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear** are not being called for this class. Why so?

I want **viewWillAppear** to be there so that when I come back to this view, I can make some change.

Comment: How you displaying the picker ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By coming back you mean coming back from `UIImagePickerController` after selecting image/media?
If you want to display the image/media you selected from `UIImagePickerController` in your view,
you can make changes in the UIImagePickercontroller delegate method :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

which gets called as soon as you select any image or media from imagePicker. You just need to set the delegate of imagePicker to the the class in which you want to display the images.